# Good beverage suggestions to get drunk but not too drunk?

Tags: recommendations, health, drinking, drink, preparation-for-drinking

If you want to get drunk to chill out and have a good time every once in a while, without going too much in the crazy side and doing very embarrassing things (vomiting, etc), then what is the best option for drinking?

What is less harmful to one's health?

And what gives the best drunk experience?

I know it depends on the amount too. But, regardless of that factor, which kinds of beverage are the best suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you my advice after 30+ years of being an adult and working in the alcohol industry for many years. Here it is: Drink the drink that has the least amount of alcohol you can stand. For me that means light beer when I know I will be at a party or another situation. I had friends of mine that would take Coors light and put it in a pitcher with crushed ice so they could drink more. It could mean putting ice cubes in your white wine. It could mean putting less alcohol in your mixed drinks. One shot instead of two.

Another tactic many take is one alcohol drink, one glass of water.

Beer is kind of self limiting because it fills you up and limits how much you can drink. Avoid things like red wine, whisky and mixed drinks with a lot of sugar. They will make you the sickest.

In the end, you can get drunk on anything and throw up and have a really bad hangover. But from some limited research (Look up Mythbusters Vodka vs Beer episode) that the clearer the alcohol (Vodka, White Wine, Light Beer) the less worse your hangover will be.

Answer (score 1):

**Good beverage suggestions to get drunk but not too drunk?**

As with anything, it will most likely depend on the individual involved.

Be a drinker and not tinker. Skip the beer and go with vodka, if it were myself. That is what I do when it comes to getting hammered! But I do avoid those bizarre flavoured ones. I like my vodka straight or with sofa water (my personal favourite), coke or ginger ale and both the vodka, whether straight or mixed should be refrigerated (personal preference). Cold vodka tastes so much better and hangovers are very mild for me.

> **Beer Drunk**
>
> Freshman 15, comes from no other then beer. People end up drinking more beer because it isn't as strong as other alcohol but it can get you really [*messed*] up if you drink an excessive amount. There are many activities that make drinking beer so much fun and encourage drinking. Beer pong, flip cup, slap cup, keg stands etc... If you can't understand what someone is saying, they've most likely drank a 24.
>
> **Vodka Drunk**
>
> Yes, you can taste the difference between good and cheap vodka. The [*crummy*] type of vodka burns your throat like rubbing alcohol, especially when you're taking shots. Expect a loud and fun person that is down to do anything if they're vodka drunk. And please, keep your vodka in the freezer (it tastes so much better.)
>
> **Wine Drunk**
>
> One of the reasons people love drinking wine, is because they think they look classy drinking it. Wine is safe and reliable but the spins can hit you out of no where. It has the ability to cheer you up when you are down but it can also drown you in tears. Best part of it all - no one will judge you for having a glass of wine mid day (perhaps a bottle over lunch)
>
> **Whiskey Drunk**
>
> Whiskey is a popular choice for dark liquor and sometimes things can get out of hand. People tend to be aggressive and turn into a completely different persona when they consume an excessive amount of whiskey. They'll most likely get into a physical fight or verbally insult the easiest target. There's a serious love-hate relationship between whiskey and people.
>
> **Tequila Drunk**
>
> Party is here! For most people, tequila comes at the end of the night when they're already drunk but they don't realize it. And tequila doesn't come in single shots, they all come together. You have shots after shots after shots and BAM - you black out. - [6 Types Of Drunk You'll Get Depending On What You Drink](https://www.narcity.com/ca/on/toronto/lifestyle/6-types-of-drunk-youll-get-depending-on-what-you-drink)

Whatever you drink to party eyed on, never get wasted on, I will never do ouzo again! I am sure that ouzo is not a nightmare drink for everyone, but it is one to be aware of the [ouzo effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouzo_effect).

> The ouzo effect (also louche or spontaneous emulsification) is a cloudy (louche) oil-in-water emulsion that is formed when water is added to ouzo and other anise-flavored liqueurs and spirits, such as pastis, rakı, arak, sambuca and absinthe. Such microemulsions occur with only minimal mixing and are highly stable.

Do not forget that drinking water can lesson the effects of a hangover.

> While food and water may ease some of the symptoms, they won’t cure a hangover. The best way to avoid one is to moderate your drinking and have water between alcoholic drinks. Remember that water won’t make you any less drunk or protect your liver. - [Alcohol myth buster](https://www.hrch.nhs.uk/_resources/assets/attachment/full/0/5026.pdf)

More information can be gleaned from the following articles:

- [Which beverages are least likely to give one a hangover? What induces hangover on a drink-to-drink basis?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/6262/5064)
- [These 4 International Drinks Will Give You The Worst Hangover Of Your Life](https://www.bustle.com/articles/15694-these-4-international-drinks-will-give-you-the-worst-hangover-of-your-life)

Answer (score 1):

My tactic has always been to have a couple of beers at the start of the night (or maybe ciders) as they fill me up and slow down consumption, but then I drink spirits and cocktails for the rest of the night at a rate which gets me tipsy or happy drunk, but not so drunk I have difficulty walking or that I embarrass myself or my friends. And this successfully means I have had 1 hangover in 40 years of drinking.

And while some subscribe to the idea that certain types of alcohol make you drunk differently to others, I have to say that doesn't match my experience. Cheap spirits can feel nasty, but any good drink can be drunk in moderation or excess and get you to the level of drunk you require.

Tequila, for example - teenagers may try cheap tequila or chartreuse shots, not good taste, but they do get you drunk quickly and cheaply. A good quality tequila or reposado, however, can be enjoyed as a sipping drink, like a good whisky or absinthe. Much more enjoyable at my age.